# couldn't start the appium server

Tags: python, appium

On trying to start the appium server, getting the following error:

```
> Checking if an update is available
> Update not available
> Starting Node Server
> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
> error: Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested port is already in use. Please make sure there's no other instance of Appium running already.
> 
> 
> Node Server Process Ended
```

Previously it is working fine. I started Selenium grid node using python. From then onwards i am getting this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? If you are using a *nix system can you do:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :4723
```

if there is any result then just kill that process.

You can try running:

```
  Windows: taskkill /F /IM node.exe
  Linux: killall node
  Mac: killall node
```

Try also installing a new version of appium from npm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like server is already in running mode. If you want to start the again, please stop the running server first.

Other case can be that same port is used by some other process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No other server is running. Even the port also not in use. I restarted the system as well, still same problem. I even tried to reinstall appium server as well. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have start appium server before when you want to start appium app;
If this condition,shutdown the appium server, then restart appium app or client.

*note:* If you killall node, the appium server also be killed.